# Laravel app.js Conflicts with Datatables

Tags: laravel, datatable

I am using datatables on a laravel project. But seems like laravels' app.js is conflicting with datatables.min.js I get this error in console.

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function`

If I remove app.js from head everything works relation to datatables but then bootstraps menu dropdowns and some other js related stuff stops working obviously because I remove app.js How can I resolve this by including both in `head` section?

**UPDATE:** Here is head section of my laravel app. Laravel version is latest 5.6

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="Yhn7OFsFoV2qKhwsF7URC9GzjwNIb8muUT2u5kkD">
<title>Application</title>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js" defer></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#users').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  searching: true,
  filter: true,
  ajax: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/data',
  columnDefs: {
    targets: [-1],
    visible: false,
    searchable: true,
  },
  columns: [
      {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
      {data: 'name', name: 'name', sortable: false},
      {data: 'email', name: 'email', sortable: false},
      {data: 'role', name: 'role'},
      {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
  ],
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api().columns([2]).every(function () {
      var column = this;
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.classList.add('form-control');
      input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'search by email..');
      input.setAttribute('name', 'search-email');

      $(input).appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
          .on('change', function () {
            column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
          });

    });
    $('.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]').addClass('form-control');
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you may miss some reference links

Answer (score 1):

It is because jquery is available to you through app.js, and you probably linked the jquery for datatable again.
 Try removing the link for jquery and it should work.

Comment: I didn't include jquery at all.

Comment: I have update my post to include the head section and mentioned the laravel version.

Comment: Remove 'defer' from <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js" defer></script>

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't specify Laravel version so I assume it's the latest stable release.

Second you didn't say how you installed datatables, I assume you just included minified source manually.

According to the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend#writing-javascript) you should be able to install `datatables` through *package.json* file (with `npm` or `yarn`, depending on your preferences).

To be clear, the `datatables` package is available in NPM repo:
https://datatables.net/download/npm

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the laravel default JS and CSS with Bootstrap. The  bootstrap javascript will work the same as App.js.
Another advantage of replacing the laravel default is Bootstrap will all you to create admin-templates like pages.That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

add defer attribute to your script tag

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript" ***defer***></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include defer attribute to your `<script src="{{ asset('js/datatables.min.js') }}" defer></script>`

Problem is that scripts are not loaded in right order. Defer runs script after document is loaded